# Spring Data - MongoDB indexing DBRef

Tags: mongodb, indexing, spring-data-mongodb, dbref

I'm using spring-data-mongodb-1.2.0.RELEASE.
I have two classes A and B where B has a reference to A and it is annotated with @DBRef.

Class A:

```
@Document(collection = "a")
public class A {
@Id
public String id;

/** The TicketGrantingTicket this is associated with. */
@Field
public String name;

public A(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Class B:

```
@Document(collection = "b")
public class B {

@Id
public String id;

@Field
public String name;

@DBRef
@Indexed
public A a;

public B(String id, String name, A a) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.a = a;
}
}
```

Since I'm quering for all instances of B that are refering to a certain A:

```
B fromDB = mongoOperations.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("a.$id").is(a1.id)), B.class);
```

I need it to be indexed.

After the first insertion of a B instance into MongoDB an index should be created.
As can be seen below it doesn't:
[image]

Does anyone know how can I create such an index ?

In addition it looks like the DBRef filed (as can be seen by the mongo shell) does not match to the format as it is defined at
[MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/#format).

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create the index with the mongo shell, but if you want to do it through code and since you are using spring-data-mongodb, use this:

`mongoTemplate.indexOps(B.class).ensureIndex(new Index().on("a", Order.ASCENDING));`

You can also specify the name of the collection if the name of your class doesn't match it:

```
mongoTemplate.indexOps("b").ensureIndex(new Index().on("a", Order.ASCENDING));
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this will work:
`@CompoundIndex(name = "b_ref_to_a", def = "{'a.id' : 1}")
@Document(collection = "b")
public class B {...}`

If not, you can call `mongoTemplate.indexOps("b").ensureIndex(...)` in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` or so

Comment: Thank's for the help. Still, why the index is not created altough it is annotated with @Indexed? and another open question is why does MongoDB documentation shows the DBRef in a different format than the one that can be seen at the Mongo shell snapshot

Comment: As for the @Indexed, it's not really documented, but I don't think it's suitable for complex types, anyway never worked for me. Personally, I use one of the two methods mentioned above to index "complex" type. As for second issue, what version of mongodb  shell are you using? try `db.d.find({},{"a.$ref" : 1, "a.$id" : 1})` what do you get?

Comment: I'm using Mongo DB and shell version 2.4.1 . I'm able to execute the next queries: db.b.find({"a.$id" : <val>},{"a.$id" : 1}) and db.b.find({"a.$id" : <val>},{"a.$ref" : 1}) but 
I can't include a.$ref and a.$id on the projection argument and the condition argument must include "a.$id" . Most important is that in order to use the index that was created on 'a', the query element must include the a.$id and a.$ref: db.b.find({a:{"$ref" : a, "$id" : <val>}})

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, for me the orid's solution worked but I had to wrap the @CompoundIndex inside a @CompoundIndexes otherwise it didn't work (I'm using Spring Roo).

```
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name = "b_ref_to_a", def = "{'a.id' : 1}")
})
@Document(collection = "b")
public class B {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DBObject indexOptions = new BasicDBObject();
indexOptions.put("a", 1);
indexOptions.put("b", 1);
indexOptions.put("c.d", 1);
indexOptions.put("e.f", 1);
CompoundIndexDefinition indexDefinition =
            new CompoundIndexDefinition(indexOptions);
mongoTemplate.indexOps(.class).ensureIndex(indexDefinition);

for unique index you can add mongoTemplate.indexOps(.class).ensureIndex(indexDefinition).unique();
```