# Mongo @DBRef unique

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

My application uses Spring Boot / JPA / MongoDB.

I map my domain classes to MongoDB using

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;
```

All is well except when trying to make a DBRef unique :

```
@DBRef @Indexed(unique = true)
private User owner;
```

I have tried different combinations of @DBRef, @Indexed (unique=true) and cannot make the DBRef unique. I can make other field-types unique, such as 'name' in the following example

```
@Indexed(unique = true)
@Size(min = 2, max = 100)
@Column(length = 100)
private String name;
```

but cannot find how to make my DBRef field unique.

Comment: Out of interest: how does the index look on the database level (`colleciton.getIndexes()`)

Comment: @xeraa - pls see code below. I have replaced the poorly named 'name' field with smeCode. The DBRef owner is the offending variable. I used db.NT_SMES.getIndexes(), owner is not indexed. smeCode and _id are listed as indexes.  (Sorry for not posting code - I couldn't get the comment to format properly)

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming from the Morphia side of mapping, but I'd try this:

```
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name = "owner", def = "{'owner.id' : 1}", unique = true)
})
```

Comment: Thx @xeraa.  A compound index is not what I want here. I want to mark a DBRef variable as unique.

Comment: Have you tried it out? This should go into the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15819034/573153
Since you don't want to index the owner but the owner's ID, you need some workaround. Therefore you'll need some kind of class level association, since the one on the attribute doesn't reach it

Comment: @xeraaI did try it, and placed 'unique' in different places. Still can't get 'owner' to be unique. I'll check the MongoTemplate documentation as per your link. Many thanks